# What is the maximum and minimum value of android audiotrack, audio type of float?

Tags: android, audio, waveform, audiotrack

I need to output the audio from the left and right channels to the headphone jack, and the headphone jack to an oscilloscope. I can't get the correct audio waveform with `Float.MAX_VALUE` and `Float.MIN_VALUE`. Usually the 16-bit audio max/min is a short type with a value of +/-32767. So you can assign values with `Short.MAX_VALUE` and `Short_MIN_VALUE`. But currently my audio is of type float, ie `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT`, and using `Float.MAX_VALUE` and `Float.MIN_VALUE` does not get the correct audio waveform in the oscilloscope. The actual audio waveform will have 0.4 milliseconds of noise before and after, but when I take the float at 3.5f or -3.5f, the shape of the waveform looks correct, but it doesn't reach the maximum. So what is the maximum and minimum audio value of the float type?
[image]
[image]
[image]

The actual audio waveform will have 0.4 milliseconds of noise before and after.
[image]

The correct waveform should be such a shape. If set to 3.5f/-3.5f, the shape is correct but not the maximum.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#write(float[],%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> ...The implementation does not clip for sample values within the nominal range [-1.0f, 1.0f], provided that all gains in the audio pipeline are less than or equal to unity (1.0f), and in the absence of post-processing effects that could add energy, such as reverb. For the convenience of applications that compute samples using filters with non-unity gain, sample values +3 dB beyond the nominal range are permitted. However such values may eventually be limited or clipped, depending on various gains and later processing in the audio path. Therefore applications are encouraged to provide samples values within the nominal range.

A 3dB power increase corresponds to an increase in voltage of sqrt(2), or roughly 1.41. So, according to the documentation, your device may be able to handle -1.41 to 1.41, but note the caveat about clipping.